# Dreamweaver deleted my file contents

Tags: windows, dreamweaver

I was developing a website using Dreamweaver. I was editing one of my PHP files and suddenly the electricity shut down and my computer turned off.

When I turned on my PC again and open the file that I was editing, all the contents were gone! When I look at the PHP file size, it's 10 KB – so that means it is not empty. I decided to open it in Notepad++, but it showed me a long string of nulls.

Is there a way to get my file contents back? I spent almost a week coding it.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but… do you have a backup? If it's been more than a week I'm sure you must have backed up your code during that time. Or put it in a repository. If you've never used a repository or don't have continuous backups, now would be a good time to start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to state what version of Windows you are using.

If you have Windows 7 then one option is that Windows may have backed up the files for you.

Right click the file and there should be a menu for "Previous Versions" which in all likelihood will have created a copy for you.

This will only work with higher versions of Vista and with Windows 7, this rather useful feature was removed again with Windows 8.